# Using Powershell to find multi-line patterns in files

Tags: regex, powershell, pattern-matching

How would I find a multiline pattern in files, such as the contents of an XML node, using Powershell?

i.e. if I were looking for the word "green" within the `deviceDescription` node, but the XML node text may span multiple lines, this doesn't work:

```
dir -r -i *.xml | select-string -Pattern "<deviceDescription>.*green.*</deviceDescription>"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, if is xml, extract the device description string treating it as such and then match for the string you want, in this case, green.

```
$x = [xml] (gc .\test.xml)
$x.deviceDescription -match "green"
```

If you don't want to go that way, you will have to use the `?s` - singleline or dotall flag which makes * match newlines:

```
$x = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\test.xml")
$x -match "(?s)<deviceDescription>.*green.*</deviceDescription>"
```

Note that you probably want to use `.*?` or this may span across multiple deviceDescription tags. Edge cases like this are reasons why you should avoid using regex for such things.

Comment: How can I output the text of the node?  I have this: $x.SelectNodes("//deviceDescription") | select-object Node