# Powershell Select-String Remove Carriage Return

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to select a carriage return in various lines in a report. Eventually, I would like to remove the carriage returns. If I use `` "`n" ``,`` "`r" ``,`"\n"`,`"\r"`, I don't get anything for the result. When I access the report in Vi, I can see the carriage return (`^L`). So I'm not sure what to do at this point but pull my hair out.

```
ls C:\DOWNLOAD\STANDARD\AUDIT*PRM3711* | %{ gc $_ | Select-String -Pattern '\** WARNING \** -  ' }
```

Result

```
** WARNING ** -  SAMPLE REPORT
** WARNING ** -  SAMPLE REPORT
** WARNING ** -  SAMPLE REPORT
** WARNING ** -  SAMPLE REPORT
```

Answer (score 1):

[`gc`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113310) returns the contents of a file as an array of lines, which will not contain line break characters.

If you need to match across lines, I would suggest the approach from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8082508/2495), e.g.:

```
$content = [IO.File]::ReadAllText( $_.FullName )
if( $content -match "(?s)..." ) {
  # use values in $matches
}
```

To remove the line break characters from a match, try `$matches[0] -replace [Environment]::NewLine` or `` $matches[0] -replace "`r*`n*" ``.

Answer (score 0):

in powershell carriage return +line feed shoud be `` `n ``

i think you can use this:

```
[string]::Join("",(gc 'C:\temp\test.txt'))
```

Comment: I already tried `n without any luck. It looks like this in Vim "** WARNING ** - ^LSAMPLE REPORT". Notice the carrot L in front of SAMPLE. When I do a Select-String within Powershell, it picks up the carriage return as a space.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell uses

```
`r`n
```

for carriage return line feed

`get-content` makes an array of strings

So you could use
 
`$result = (cat C:\DOWNLOAD\STANDARD\AUDIT*PRM3711* | where { $_ -like '** WARNING ** -  ' } )
$result = $result -replace '** WARNING ** -  ' , 'rn** WARNING ** -  '`

Alternatively, I think in PS3 you can make it one long line instead of an array by using 
`` get-content -delimiter `0 ``

I don't have a PS3 box in front of me right now....

Comment: Aaand it ate the back ticks...  <code>-replace "pattern", "backtick R backtick N pattern"</code>