# Verify blocks of text in a file with powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a folder full of Cisco configurations. I am having a difficult time trying to find a way to verify strings of commands that are in the configuration.

I have no problem with single line commands and am currently using the following for that with 100% success:

```
Get-childitem -path $Path -recurse |foreach-object{if (-not (select-string -inputobject $_ -Pattern "banner login")){$_}} | select name | Out-file $OutPath\OutputName.txt
```

I would like to verify commands such as this:

```
    access-list 69 remark Name
    access-list 69 permit x.x.x.x
    access-list 69 permit x.x.x.x
    access-list 69 permit x.x.x.x
```

The 4 lines will be the same through out all configurations. I have tried..

```
    Get-childitem -path $Path -recurse |foreach-object{if (-not (select-string -inputobject $_ -Pattern "access-list 69 remark Name", "access-class xx in", "access-list 69 permit x.x.x.x", "access-list 69 permit x.x.x.x", "access-list 69 permit x.x.x.x")){$_}} | select name | Out-file $OutPath\OutputText.txt
```

...but that only checks for each of those commands separately and reports all configuration files as compliant. I am trying to verify that specific block in that exact order. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will preserve order and take care of whitespace/newlines:

```
$CfgBlock = @(
    'access-list 69 remark Name',
    'access-class xx in',
    'access-list 69 permit x.x.x.x',
    'access-list 69 permit x.x.x.x',
    'access-list 69 permit x.x.x.x'
) 

$CfgRegex = '\s*' + (($CfgBlock -split '\s+' | ForEach-Object {[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join '\s+') + '\s*'

Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse | Where-Object {
    (Get-Content -Path $_.FullName -Raw) -notmatch $CfgRegex
} | Select-Object -Property Name | Out-file $OutPath\OutputText.txt
```

Comment: Need to be careful. Not they they will cause an issue but you have regex control characters in your `$CfgBlock`. If the op uses this logic elsewhere he might be in for a surprise

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much, beatcracker!

Comment: @Matt Thanks, missed that. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `-match`, similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082385/using-powershell-to-find-multi-line-patterns-in-files).

Declare your search string outside that long line of code:

```
$str = @"
access-list 69 remark Name
access-list 69 permit x.x.x.x
access-list 69 permit x.x.x.x
access-list 69 permit x.x.x.x
"@
```

Apart from formatting, the only change is the `Select-String` to `-match`:

```
Get-childitem -path $Path -recurse | foreach-object {
   If (-not (([IO.File]::ReadAllText($_.FullName)) -match ".*$str.*")) {
      $_
   }
} | Select Name | Out-file $OutPath\OutputText.txt
```

Comment: Need to be careful. Not they they will cause an issue but you have regex control characters in your `$str `. If the op uses this logic elsewhere he might be in for a surprise